# conv.ask() wait until audio is complete

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I am building a 'game' using the actions-sdk and nodejs. For this game one feature requires that the audo to finish before taking user input. Is it possible using conv.ask() to ignore input from the text intent until the audio is complete? Also is there anyway to put a callback on conv.ask() for when audio is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the normal behavior of the Assistant - the microphone remains closed until audio is done, and then it opens the mic for the user to reply. However - the user can interrupt the Assistant at any point with the hotword ("Hey, Google"). There is no way to block this, but it isn't really clear why you want to prevent them from doing so.

There is also no way to put a callback on when the audio is delivered. Remember that `conv.ask()` runs on your server - not on the local device (although the audio is played on that device).

If you're looking to do something like ask a question, and then give them 15 seconds to answer it, you might look into seeing if a Media Response could help. If you ask the question along with a Media Response, they can interrupt the audio with "Hey Google" and the answer, or the Media will finish and send you an event when it is completed.

Comment: so i am only testing on a phone atm and that isnt how it behaves. Are you saying a smart speaker would not allow the interrupt?

Comment: Which isn't how it behaves? Both the smart speaker and the mobile **do** allow the interrupts, which is what I said, but require the user to say "hey google" to do the interruption.

Comment: OK, well maybe I was getting confused because I am testing this on my phone and tapping the mic button as it wasnt always prompting for input automatically. I am going to mark this as solved. Thanks for the input and suggestions about the Media Response.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Media Response: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses

It has a callback when the audio finishes. In the callback you could do a conv.ask to prompt the user for input.

Comment: so media response can be used for text / text to speech? Not just audo / images etc.

Comment: Not exactly, but you can append a short (<1sec) Media Response as part of the speech and when that finishes, you'll get the notification on your server. But you still then need to reply to that with a prompt of some sort.